# C++ logical negated comparison operator doesn't work

Tags: c++

I have a pretty simple class `foo`, that implements the `<` operator. I tried to implement a descending sort by negating the result of the operator like here:

```cpp
std::sort(foos_.begin(), foos_.end(), 
  [](Foo& a, Foo& b) { return !(a < b); }
);
```

Unfortunately, this gives me a `SIGSEGV` error. I guess because the result of the comparison is not reasonable. But I'm wondering why this is? Shouldn't `!(a < b)` be the same as `(b < a)`?

The following code works as expected:

```cpp
std::sort(foos_.begin(), foos_.end(), 
  [](Foo& a, Foo& b) { return (b < a); }
);
```

The implementation of the operator is straight forward:

```cpp
bool Foo::operator<(Foo const& a) const { 
  return this->some_float_value < a.some_float_value;  
}
```

Comment: `!(a < b) == (b <= a)`

Comment: Those do not have the same meaning. Look into what strict weak ordering is.

Comment: It needs to return false for equal elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Shouldn't `!(a < b)` be the same as `(b < a)`?

no, `!(a < b)` is equivalent to `b <= a`.

`<=` and `>=` doesn't respect strict weak ordering.

You need:

```
std::sort(foos_.begin(), foos_.end(), 
  [](const Foo& a, const Foo& b) { return b < a; }
);
```